# Button, Timeout, Alerts Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, typeerror

I have 2 buttons and I want to click "Button1" first and after 5 sec. "Button2" 
and after 10 more sec. redirect to another url.

```
document.getElementById('Button1').click();
alert("After clicking Button1");
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('Button2').click();
}, 5000);
alert("After clicking Button2");
setTimeout(function(){
window.location.href="http://google.com";
}, 10000);
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null.

The buttons work and click but the code for redirecting doesn't. The strange thing is I used alerts to check the code and it first runs the alerts and after that clicks "Button1" and after that "Button2" and after that I get the Error and it doesn't continue to execute the last code. I have no idea what to do..

Comment: `Button2` does not exist

Comment: @John Cena Which line is the error appearing at?

Answer (score 1):

I think your second alert statement is misplaced.
Try this:

```
document.getElementById('Button1').click();
alert("After clicking Button1");

// wait 5 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('Button2').click();
    alert("After clicking Button2");

    // wait 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href="http://google.com";
    }, 10000);
}, 5000);
```

Make sure that Button2 exists, as the error you are getting indicates that it does not.
Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<button id="Button1">this is button 1</button>
<button id="Button2">this is button 2</button>
```

Comment: The button exists cuz after i click the second button it gets a userslot for the user.

Comment: Try to restructure your code (by nesting the setTimeouts like I have) and see if that changes things